# Sybase versions for merge function

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How do I know The merge function for which version it suports in sybase ? I have sybase 15 but there are developers using sybase 12. In this [link](http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbreference_en11/merge-statement.html) they didnt mention for which versions the function works, I am afraid I use it and some old sybase version dont support it .

Comment: I'm pretty sure the manual documents in which version this is available.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is the sybase center they didnt mention any version http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/commands89.htm

Comment: it says **Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7** right at the top of the sybase center link and "SQL Anywhere 11.0.0* right at the top in the link from your question. You are aware that there is a big difference between "SQL Anywhere" and "Adaptive Server Enterprise"?

Comment: It seems like the developers are using SQLAnywere, and @moudiz has ASE.